# stopping a event listener while a code is running?

Tags: javascript, events

```
function errBlink()
{
    var check=true;
    var borColor=this.style.borderColor;
    var bxShad=this.style.boxShadow;

    var blink=setInterval(blinker(this),300);

    setTimeout(resetBox(this),2000);

    function resetBox(ele)
    {
        clearInterval(blink);
        ele.style.borderColor=borColor;    
        ele.style.boxShadow=bxShad;
    }

    function blinker(ele)
    {
        if(check)
        {
            ele.style.borderColor='red';
            ele.style.boxShadow='0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(255,0,13,1)';
            check=false'
        }else
        {
            ele.style.borderColor='white';
            ele.style.boxShadow='0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(00,00,00,1)';
            check=true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to stop listening to keydown events only while this code is running because during the setinterval if any key is pressed this resets this code running all over again and seems to be queue if kept pressing really for too long.

Comment: While what code is running?

Comment: Why not not just have a variable and it set to false when the code Is running and if code is false don't do event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than disabling keydown events which could interfere with other functionality on your site, I would suggest using another flag (similar to what you have done with `check`).

For example, you could make a flag `isBlinking`, set it to true when your function starts, false when your function ends, and only run your code `if(!isBlinking)`.